# Making aggregates pageble in DDD

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I have one aggregate to pass through Controller, Service and Repository layers. According to DDD, there is no related information about eloquent models in aggregate. I need to do pagination for that aggregate that repository returns information about it.

Is it more suitable create another object for it or can we put information about pagination to aggregates in DDD?

Comment: Can you please be more specific, what do you want to paginate? Several aggregate instances? Is the aggregate a compound object with potentially huge collections that you want to pagginate? 2nd point would be, you don't pass your aggregates through App Controllers, only your DTO should reach that layer. Aggregates play a role in the domain between repositoty and service layers,

Comment: The controller creates aggregates from json, then pass it to service. Is it wrong in DDD? Aggregate holds lots of entity but I do not care the entities at this moment except one entity that  will paginate it. For instance, SchoolAggregate holds school, student, etc. Just basic school eloquent model will be paginated. Repository will convert to eloquent model to aggregate. At this moment, should aggregate contain pagination information like current_page or should I create another object like PageableAggregate?

Comment: there are some points here: first from the JSON, a DTO shoud be generated. That is in turn mapped to an aggregate, and that is what you pass to your service. In other words, your aggregate shouldn't be the JSON that you show to the outside world, because your couple your API (client contrat) to the domain implementation.

Comment: 2nd - An aggregate is usualy an entitiy (with identity of course), an all it subparts are defined also by the identity of the root aggregate. A good example coul de an order with its order items, they belong to the order, and their identity and lifecycle are tied to the order's. In your case, stuff like student & school sounds alot like entities (aggregate roots) on their own right (unless in your domain they just represent value objects, but still you may want to reconsider your design).

Comment: what you seem to need, is to model separatedly a School agregate, a Student aggregate, etc. Use your School repository to get that school list you want (in your repository you define a page size). That list is what you give back to your domain layer, you turn your List of Schools into a list of SchoolsDTOs, and that is what you push to your API/controller layer.

Answer (score 2):

> can we put information about pagination to aggregates in DDD?

That's usually an error; unless "pagination" is a real thing in your domain model, it sounds like an application concern rather than a domain concern.

You might, for instance, have methods on your *repository* that return pages of results taken from a set of aggregates.